# Make www a subdomain.

Tags: bug, status-completed, meta

Try going to

http://www.stackapps.com

Apparently `www` is not a subdomain of stackapps.com

Anyone who tries to get to the site by prepending the `www` will be confused, as it is standard to point that to the main domain.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think www.stackapps.com should be redirected to stackapps.com, currently can see the same page but cookies validation looks failing

Comment: Hmmm. For me, it won't work at all.